# Calculate date for which the stock becomes 0 in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the current stock for each material:

[Stock table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8OL7.png)

I have another table with the demand for each material on each day (there might be days without demand for a certain material).
[Requirements table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vjpd.png)

I want to get a calculated table with the material and the date for which its stock becomes 0. On the example showed would be like this:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yFUD.png)

I have been trying different approaches, even with the help of AI, but never gotten to the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two tables for stock table and requirements table. Relate the two tables by the Material - Material columns.
   [image]
2. Create two new measures.

   Total Stock Ordered =
   var _currdate=MAX('Requirements Table'[Date of requirement])
   return
   CALCULATE(
   SUM('Requirements Table'[Qty Required]),
   FILTER(
   ALLSELECTED('Requirements Table'[Date of requirement]),
   ISONORAFTER('Requirements Table'[Date of requirement], _currdate, DESC)
   )
   )

   Running Total =
   var currStock = LOOKUPVALUE('stock table'[Current Stock],'stock table'[Material],SELECTEDVALUE('Requirements Table'[Material]))
   return
   currStock - [Total Stock Ordered]

Then you can use the Running Total measure to filter the table or highlight the table when we are out of stock.

[image]

You can look at the solution file here:
https://github.com/dataDad/stackOverflow/blob/main/Stock%20Out%20Date.pbix